# Package pdfpages interrupts customization with enumitem

Tags: enumitem, pdfpages

I have a longer work and in that I want include a pdf-file and also I have customize enumerate-items with package `enumitem`. With inculded package `pdfpages` I get errors.

Is it possible to include `pdfpages` and to keep my customization with enumitem? Minimal working example below.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% um PDF-Dateien einbinden zu können ---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% Tabellen -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % horizontale Linien in Tabellen
\usepackage{longtable}                  % lange Tabellen
\usepackage{ragged2e,array}             % für Ausrichtung der Tabellen(-spalten/-zellen)

% Programmierung der Auflistung der Interviewitems -------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{Kategorie}
\setcounter{Kategorie}{0}
\newcounter{Frage}
\setcounter{Frage}{1}

\newcommand{\KategoriePlus}{%
  \addtocounter{Kategorie}{1}%
  [\Alph{Kategorie}]%
  \setcounter{Frage}{1}%
}

\newcommand{\FragePlus}{%
  \theFrage%
  \addtocounter{Frage}{1}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Einleitung}

\blindtext[3]

\chapter{Anhang}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{longtable}[l]{>{\RaggedRight}p{5.75cm}>{\RaggedRight}p{10.25cm}} \toprule

Inhalt & Frage \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{minipage}[t]{16cm}
\bfseries \begin{enumerate}[label=\KategoriePlus] \item Allgemeine Daten \end{enumerate} \end{minipage}} \\
Soziodemografische Daten der Versuchsperson &
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm} \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph{Kategorie}.\FragePlus]
\item Alter
\item Geschlecht
\item Schulabschluss
\end{enumerate} \end{minipage} \\ \bottomrule

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `pdfpages` loads package `calc` that makes `\setcounter` and `\addtocounter` more fragile, especially if they are used inside option `label` of package `enumitem`'s redefined environment `enumerate`.

The best solution would be to avoid the counter assignments in `label`. because this option is intended for *formatting* the label and nothing else. If a later version of `enumitem` would call the code of `\label` twice per `\item`, then it would also disturb the counter assignments.

Thus the following is only a crude hack, using robust counter assignments, but not curing the underlying problem:

```
\newcommand{\KategoriePlus}{%
  % \stepcounter{Kategorie}%
  \global\advance\value{Kategorie} by 1\relax
  [\Alph{Kategorie}]%
  % \setcounter{Frage}{1}%
  \global\value{Frage}=1\relax
}

\newcommand{\FragePlus}{%
  \theFrage
  % \stepcounter{Frage}%
  \global\advance\value{Frage} by 1\relax
}
```